# SQL query for all records that are not the most recent

Tags: sql, join, max, inner-join

I am trying to get all the record_ids of all the entries of a **specific individualid** (in this example 'nest22') that are not currently **loaded** that are **not the most recent**.  The query I wrote to get the most recent record_id works however when I try to filter by the results of that something is off and I cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
SELECT record_id AS recid, individualid AS ind, load_status AS load
  FROM tbl t1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT record_id, individualid , load_status, created_at
               FROM tbl
              INNER JOIN( SELECT individualid AS indid,
                                 MAX( created_at) AS max_create
                            FROM tbl
                           GROUP BY individualid) ms ON individualid = indid 
                                                     AND created_at = max_create
              WHERE individualid LIKE 'nest22'
                AND load_status NOT LIKE 'LOADED') t2 ON recid = record_id
 WHERE load NOT LIKE 'LOADED'
   AND individualid LIKE 'nest22'
   AND record_id = NULL
```

The table itself looks like this

```
record_id  | individualid | created_at | load_status
-----------+--------------+------------+------------
1          |nest22        |9/16/2021   | PENDING
2          |nest22        |9/13/2021   | PENDING
3          |nest22        |9/10/2021   | PENDING
4          |nest22        |9/1/2021    | LOADED
5          |nest23        |9/10/2021   | PENDING
```

I would like the query to return record_id's 2 & 3

Comment: What makes you think something is off? Do you think you get wrong result rows? Too many? Too few? Is it just a gut feeling?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Usually it is not possible to define alias names in the `SELECT` clause and refer to these alias names in the `ON` clauses and `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I see you are joining the tbl rows at last on record_id. So record_id is not unique in the table, right? (Otherwise you would join each row with itself, which wouldn't seem to make sense.) You get the rows with the maximum dates per individualid and then you join all rows that have the same record_id. So at last you don't have only the rows with max date, but others as well. Correct?

Comment: @th I realize I should have added this in but I get this error when I attempt to query. {"error":"ERROR: column \"created_at\" does not exist\nLINE 7: max(\"created_at\") AS \"max_create\" FROM (SELECT \"form_151841_...\n ^\n"}

Comment: Sounds like there is no created_at column in tbl. Maybe a typo? As to the overall query: tell us what exactly you are trying to select. maybe we can help you better then.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am trying to select all the record_id's of each entry where individualid == nest22 and the load_status !== 'LOADED' and not the most recently created.  Lines the query within the LEFT JOIN correctly retrieves the most recently created nest22 entry (so the column does exist).  I want to use the record id retrieved with it to filter the table to what I want

Comment: You haven't answerd which DBMS you are using. And while it *sounds* like the record_id is the table's primary key and your sample data seems to support this, you haven't answered whether this is true. We must still*assume* that record_id is unique. It is also not really clear what "newest" refers to. The newest in the table? The newest for nest22? The newest unloaded? The newest unloaded for nest22? I have writen an answer and O. Jones has done so earlier. But we were forced to guess. Be more precise in describing the problem if you want good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for `NOT IN`. Let's start with a subquery to get the dates of most recent qualified records.

```sql
                      SELECT individualid, MAX(created_at) created_at
                        FROM tbl
                       WHERE load_status <> 'LOADED'
                       GROUP BY individualid
```

Then, let's wrap that in another subquery to get the record_ids of those most recent records.

```sql
              SELECT a.record_id
                FROM tbl a
                JOIN (
                      SELECT individualid, MAX(created_at) created_at
                        FROM tbl
                       WHERE load_status <> 'LOADED'
                       GROUP BY individualid
                     ) b   ON a.individualid = b.individualid
                          AND a.created_at = b.created_at
```

Then, let's use that in a main query. [Check it out here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubdAoEQh5Q9c6yqSUdvx8w/1).

```sql
SELECT record_id AS recid, individualid AS ind, load_status AS load
  FROM tbl
 WHERE record_id NOT IN (
              SELECT a.record_id
                FROM tbl a
                JOIN (
                      SELECT individualid, MAX(created_at) created_at
                        FROM tbl
                       WHERE load_status <> 'LOADED'
                       GROUP BY individualid
                     ) b   ON a.individualid = b.individualid
                          AND a.created_at = b.created_at
                )
  AND load_status <> 'LOADED'
  AND individualid = 'nest22'
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't answered which DBMS you are using, so here is an answer with standard SQL queries.

You want to show all rows except

- the newest row
- rows with individualid <> 'nest22'
- rows with load_status = 'LOADED'

Here it is important to consider in what order to apply the criteria. If we just pick the rows with matching individualid and load_status then we cannot see from this data set, if one of its rows is the newest row, because we don't know whether our criteria has already removed the newest row or not. We'll have to look up the original table again. If, however, we remove the newest row first, we can then remove the undesired individualid and load_status from that data set.

Here are the two options:

**Query #1**

```
select *
from tbl
where individualid = 'nest22'
and load_status <> 'LOADED'
and created_at <> (select max(created_at) from tbl);
```

**Query #2**

```
select *
from
(
  select *
  from tbl
  order by created_at desc
  offset 1 row
) without_newest
where individualid = 'nest22'
and load_status <> 'LOADED';
```

Both queries consider created_at to be unique in the table, so the greatest created_at means the newest row.

There are other ways to achieve the same. The newest row is the one with the greatest date, which can also be expressed as the row for which no other row with a greater date exists, i.e. we could use an `EXISTS` clause for this. We could also number the rows (with `ROW_NUMBER`) in descending order and skip the row #1, because that would be the newest.

At last, seeing that you forgot to tell us there is a syntax error in your query, forgot to answer the question regarding the DBMS, forgot to answer whether record_id is unique in the table, it may well be that you haven't decribed the task properly. If for instance this is not about the newest row in the table, but about nest22's newest row or the last unloaded row or nest22's last unloaded row, then you'd have to adjust the queries accordingly.